# amd-gpu-pro problems 16.04 with r9 270x

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

Trying to load the amdgpu pro proprietary drivers.  I can login but the desktop is blank with flickering of windows I try to open with right click.  I believe this is a known problem and is covered here; [amdgpu-pro-install on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with R9 285 and RX 480](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480/797598#797598)

I have applied the patch and managed to get it compiling, but after installing the .deb packages and rebooting I still have the same issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Officially [AMDGPU-PRO Driver for Linux® – Release Notes](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx) the R9 270x is NOT supported by the PRO driver. Try the open source option instead.

Comment: The above comment notwithstanding, they are planning to add support for Southern Island cards sometime later this year.

Comment: ...aaand I guess it wasn't going to be by the end of the year. AMD appears to be dragging their heels on this one.