# 16.04 Blank screen with AMD 460 graphics and gnome 3 (resolved with patch)

Tags: drivers, gnome, amd-graphics

I have an MSI Radeon RX460 graphics card, and have installed the latest (as of today) amdgpu-pro-driver, amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz. So far so good, good login screen at full 4k resolution.  However, when I log in to a gnome 3 session, I get blank screens with a few lines of noise along the bottom of one monitor. There are windows there as the mouse cursor (which is displayed) changes as it's moved around. 2 monitors in use, 4K secondary, 2560x1440 primary.

Unity works fine, as does gnome flashback (both metacity and compiz), but not gnome, gnome classic nor cinnamon.  However, my preferred desktop is gnome 3, and I'd like it to work.

uname -a says:

```
Linux chaos2 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci | grep -i VGA says:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 67ef (rev cf)
```

lsmod|grep amdgpu says:

```
amdgpu               1961984  3
ttm                    94208  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        147456  2 i915,amdgpu
drm                   364544  7 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu
```

Can anyone suggest any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480](http://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480)

Comment: I don't believe there is much in common with that issue - that was regarding boot up problems and installation issues.  My install was faultless, and the graphics displayed (and performance)  is fine - apart from with the named desktops, gnome 3 in particular.

Comment: You may have missed the relevant part from that link "We just have to wait for an official fix for this issue, until then this is a good way to get the amdgpu-pro driver working on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04". The COGL package in Gnome 3 is a known issue with AMDGPU-Pro driver on 16.04 (possible prior version IDK); however up to you whether you keep working with a blank screen or not. [Bug 96768 - Black screen past login with RX 480, Ubuntu 16.04 and AMDgpu-pro 16.30](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96768)

Comment: You are correct, I did miss the link, thanks for pointing it out.  I applied the patch suggested using the method at https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/amd-linux/881527-amdgpu-pro-16-30-released-with-rx-480-support/page5 (a couple of posts down), and now have gnome 3 working.  Your assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from GrannySez, I applied the patch using the method at phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/… (a couple of posts down), and now have gnome 3 working.  The package build process does fail, but manually installing the library works.  The compiled library is much larger than the original, most likely because it is unstripped, but it works fine anyhow.  If you apply the fix manually in this way be sure to put a hold on the cogl package, as suggested in the link.