# Problem with install drivers to r9 290 on ubuntu 16.04 gnome

Tags: drivers, 16.04, gnome, radeon, gpu

After instalation amdgpu-pro the screan doesn't display and i can see only corsour. I found the solution here [amdgpu-pro-install on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with R9 285 and RX 480](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480) but after exute a command  apt-get source cogl there is error:

`WARNING: packeting "cogl" is managed in system of control version "Svn" at:
svn://svn.debian.org/pkg-gnome/desktop/unstable/cogl
It's necessary to download 1652 kB sources archives.
WARNING: Some packiets could be not verificated
  cogl
E: Some packiets could be not verificated`
Sorry my English is not very well. Error code is translated by me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Log out
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to get a terminal login
3. Logged in
4. `apt-get source cogl`
5. Log out by typing `logout`
6. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the graphical login screeen
7. Login again

Hope this helps