# Samsung Ativ Book 9 lite Ubuntu Gnome Slow Performance

Tags: gnome, gpu-driver

Can someone with a Samsung Ative Book 9 lite recommend a fix?

My laptop struggles running 16.04 gnome. The UI is very slow and the scrolling is sluggish. I believe this is a driver problem, but I can't find solutions.

Windows 10 runs smoothly, with no lag scrolling through web pages like Youtube and Facebook, but Ubuntu is lagging. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the proprietary driver in the application and updates section (where you can add keys). There you can search for alternative drivers for the graphics card. But the normal preinstalled driver also worked without problems.

Comment: what ubuntu gnome version are you using?

Comment: please guide me because i cant get this to work.

Comment: when i view the tab additional drivers on software and updates, i can only see the microcode thing. no video drivers there.

Comment: are u sure you got samsung ativ book 9 lite? maybe u got the non-lite version?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Samsung. But erverything runs very smooth. Maybe you can install a Gnome-shell-extensenion called Impatience. It can speed up the animations of the UI. I have also disabled all unneeded Programs and installed Chrome. For Graphic i have installed the property Driver. Also you can install Samsung-tools for your samsung, so you can controll Fans (but you have to install ubuntu in bios-legacy-mode and not UEFI-mode). Thermald for not getting a too hot notebook. And also you should make a update. The newest version is 16.10 so maybe a dist-upgrade. Hope this make things better.

Comment: did you install the amdgpu-pro driver? many thanks for the answer :D

Comment: What proprietary driver did you install? Is it the new amdgpu-pro drivers?

Comment: please help me, lars.

Comment: cant install amdgpu-pro. stuck on building initial module...

Comment: someone help me please.

Comment: help me someone please. im struggling with this. cant get this to work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/797598/665251 you should try out this answer

Answer (score 0):

I had installed ubuntu-gnome 16.04. but there were also no problems. with a dist-upgrade i have upgraded to 16.10. i installed no gpu drivers. everything runs smooth and with 16.10 i have a better battery time. thats all. also the lite version.

Comment: can i add you on facebook so that you can help me more

Comment: i'll download 16.10

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked out-of-the-box. But i have the feeling 16.10 runs smoother. I use chrome for webbrowser and turned off gpu-using.  I still use the preinstalled drivers. Do you have installed the Impaciente gnome-shell-extension. when i put it to zero, animations speeded up. hope it will help you with your problems. i have no FB account.