# amdgpu-pro - Stuck on login screen / Ubuntu on HP Probook 470 G3

Tags: drivers, graphics, hp, amd-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu on my HP Probook 470 G3

Everything works fine, except the system often freezes, giving messages with `amdgpu...` so i decided to install AMD's `amdgpu-pro` driver. Sadly, using that driver, i'm not even able to login anymore. Trying to log in, the screen just turns black and a little later the login screen comes up again.

I uninstalled the driver using `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`. But that doesn't solve the problem with the freezing.

Is there anyone running Ubuntu on a HP Probook 470 G3, who got rid of the freezes?

---

### System Information

- HP Probook 470 G3
- AMD Radeon R7 M340 (1 or 2 GB DDR3 dedicated, switchable)
- Ubuntu 16.04

The mentioned `amdgpu-pro` driver was: amdgpu-pro 16.60 for Ubuntu 16.04

---

### Some additional notes:

- I think getting the `amdgpu-pro` driver to work could solve the problem, as the freezes seem to be related to the graphics card power management. The notebook uses a hybrid graphics system and the crashes always seem to occure when the cards switch (for example it always crashes on logout or when you attach / detach a secondary monitor)
- Using the `amdgpu-pro` driver and starting the session with `startx` command instead of using `lightdm` service directly, i found some errors in `Xorg.0.log` that match with the errors mentioned in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860788/undefined-symbol-is64bitelf), which sadly wasn't ever answered.

  ```
  [    46.106] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so: undefined symbol: is64bitelf)
  [    46.106] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
  [    46.118] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: is64bitelf)
  [    46.118] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
  ```

  maybe just somehow adding the missing reference to `is64bitelf` would solve the problem?
- Already tried the following drivers: Default `Xorg` driver delivered with Ubuntu, the mentioned `amdgpu-pro` driver by AMD and Obiaf's Xorg optimizations (this one resulted in black window borders and context menus)

---

Any help would be appreciated!

---

### Edit:

Output of `dmesg`:

```
    [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
    can't get the mac of 5
    [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 12 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 13 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 15 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 5 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 5 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 6 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 6 succeeded in 5 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 7 succeeded in 5 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 8 succeeded in 5 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
    [drm] ring test on 10 succeeded in 4 usecs
    VI should always have 2 performance levels
    amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GPU pci config reset
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [amdgpu-pro-install on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with R9 285 and RX 480](http://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Well, the installation works fine, so it seems to be a different problem, but giving the output of `dmesg` like in that post is a good idea, i'll edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

Amdgpu-pro do not work with AMD hybrid gpu's.
Not yet.

the latest info on supported cards with the amdgpu-pro (beta) driver (as well as download and installation instructions) can be found [here.](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx)

Comment: Ah i see.. is there some workarround to get rid of the freezing or do i just have to wait until the drivers are available?

Comment: This link is outdated. The last amdgpu-pro version is 16.60. Here the updated link: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: But, even the last amdgpu-pro 16.60 do not work for amd hybrid gpu, like r7m265.